# Cross-reference js-object variables when creating object

Tags: javascript, extjs, this-pointer

## Summary:

I want to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
{a: 'A',b: this.a}
```

...by using some other pointer like `{a: 'A',b: self.a}` or `{a: 'A',b: own.a}` or anything else...

## Full question:

I'm trying to extend MyBaseModule using Ext.extend, and need to cross-reference values in the extension object passed to Ext.extend().

Since I'm not yet in context of MyModule, I'm not able to use **this** to reference the object (See example below line 12). Is there any other way to reference values like this without creating the object first?

```
1 MyModule = Ext.extend(MyBaseModule, {
2   dataStores: {
3       myDataStore: new Ext.data.Store({...})
4   },
5
6   myGridDefinition: {
7       id:                 'myGridDefinitionPanel',
8       bodyBorder:         false,
9       items: [{
10          xtype:          'grid',
11          id:             'myGridDefinitionGrid',
12          store:          this.dataStores.myDataStore
13      }]
14  }
15 });
```

Or is the following the only solution?
I would like to avoid this if possible, as I find it less readable for large extension definitions.

```
1 var extensionObject = {
2   dataStores: {
3       myDataStore: new Ext.data.Store({...})
4   },
5
6   myGridDefinition: {
7       id:                 'myGridDefinitionPanel',
8       bodyBorder:         false,
9       items: [{
10          xtype:          'grid',
11          id:             'myGridDefinitionGrid'
12      }]
13  }
14 };
15
16 extensionObject.locationsGrid.items[0].store = extensionObject.dataStores.locations;
17
18 MyModule = Ext.extend(MyBaseModule, extensionObject);
```

Comment: I realize that the object is not yet created when I want to access it's properties, so what I'm looking for is some sort of built-in helper feature in the JavaScript language to tell it to resolve the references after the object is created...

Hmm... the more I look at this, the more unlikely it seems to me that such a feature would exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just build the object progressively:

```
var dataStores = {
    myDataStore: new Ext.data.Store({...})
};

var extensionObject = {
    dataStores: dataStores,
    myGridDefinition: {
        id: 'myGridDefinitionPanel',
        bodyBorder: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'grid',
            id: 'myGridDefinitionGrid',
            store: dataStores.myDataStore
        }]
    }
};
```

Another approach:

```
var extensionObject = {
    dataStores: {
        myDataStore: new Ext.data.Store({...})
    }
};

extensionObject.myGridDefinition = {
    id: 'myGridDefinitionPanel',
    bodyBorder: false,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        id: 'myGridDefinitionGrid',
        store: extensionObject.dataStores.myDataStore
    }]
};
```

Comment: I guess there is no other way. I was hoping to avoid fragmenting the object definition like this, but I'm probably just beeing difficult...